# Copy files from different DVDs?

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

Im using ISDone library. So how to copy external files from different dvd's to one folder? I dont know why, but FileCopy() function doesnt work for me.

```
    FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{src}\data.part01.rar'),'{app}', true);
    if not ShowChangeDiskWindow ('Insert DVD2...',
    ExpandConstant('{src}\'),'data.part02.rar') then break;
```

Comment: What is exactly the issue ? Do you have a error message ? What did you try to get it working ? Please improve your question so that we can provide better help.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange but script works in this way:

```
FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{src}' + '\data.part01.rar'),'{app}' + '\data.part01.rar', false);
```

Comment: This would definitely fail because there is no such path `{app}` in your system. From what I can see, you missed to expand the target file name path, and missed the fact that it must be the file name, not just the path. Write this instead `FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{src}\data.part01.rar'), ExpandConstant('{app}\data.part01.rar', False);`.

Comment: If you pass unexpanded `{app}` string as a part of the target file name to the Inno Setup's `FileCopy` function, that function will fail to execute (you can, or better yet, you should check the returned boolean value to convince yourself). I don't get your picture response; I just know that this is wrong.